# get user email and location in facebook

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am stuck in the middle.I am not able to retreive the user email and location using the following code.Can anybody help me fix the issue?

```
[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
         NSLog(@"%@",user);
     }
 }];
```

Basically I  am using Facebook 3.2 SDK and Following Scrumptious sample.I cant figure how can I retrieve the user emailID and location from it?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was bit ignorant about the FBLOGINVIEW class.There'a property called `readPermission` through which you can set all the required read permissions from [FBLoginView](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.0/class/FBLoginView/).